# How can I write japanese characters?

Tags: language-support, input-language, japanese

I'm not Japanese but I'm learning the language and I want to know how to write these characters. I already searched how to do it and found Ibus-anthy but it's seriously buggy for me for some reason.

Does someone knows alternatives to this program? I'm in lubuntu jammy jellyfish 22.3 with LQXT desktop environment as default.

Comment: "Buggy"? Maybe you simply didn't set it up correctly? Yes, there are alternatives as you can find out yourself. But if you want help to set it up correctly, maybe a better idea is to explain what you did with respect to ibus-anthy and what the actual problem is.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. `ibus-mozc` and `fcitx-mozc` are popular now. After the installation, you need to execute `im-setup` and choose `ibus` or `fcitx` you've installed then restart computer and `fcitx-autostart` for `fcitx` to activate daemon. Next up, open Settings > keyboard and set `Mozc` to inpur methods. Finally, open `ibus-setup` or `fcitx-config` to be able to switch between languages. It's a long way to do this. Check [this](https://hirooka.pro/ubuntu-22-04-lts-japanese-input-ibus-fcitx-mozc/) out.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka: 1. `s/im-setup/im-config/` 2. Please suggest `fcitx5`, not `fcitx (4)`. It's 2023.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, `im-config` is my typo, sorry. But `fcitx5` has more bugs than `fcitx`. Once I installed `fcitx5` but got back to `fcitx` in a few days. I cannot recall the exact issue, but I wasn't on it.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka: As regards bugs, is that generally true? `fcitx` is in maintenance mode, and the default variant is `fcitx5` in both Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, I tried to install `fcitx5-mozc` and successfully recall why I didn't use it. When I tried it a year ago, Firefox doesn't accept Japanese conversion via fcitx5. And fcitx5 often broke. Especially, when I switch En <> JP, it goes unresponsive. I could use it first 5 minutes, but it went wrong again. `fcitx(4)` has never given me any troubles for 5 years or more. I think only European people understand me, why would I change my tools I like and it is not broken.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka: `fcitx5` works fine with Firefox. I'm using it with Mozc right now: 寿司　There was an issue with `fcitx5` and snaps, but that was [resolved 2 years ago](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/im-config/0.47-1). As regards toggling, it did take me a while before having figured out how it works with `fcitx5`. I don't suggest that *you* should replace a framework which is not broken. But please don't let your personal config issues guide you when giving advice here.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka: I think I would be able to help, but the way the above question is currently worded is not an invitation to elaborate on the topic.